# How to speed up executing delete and update query in SQL CE?

Tags: sql-server-ce, sql-delete

I create one small application to delete and update data to database SQL CE

I only update or delete  approximately 20-30 records but take 10 seconds >> very slow

update Product set Name='dell' where Id='Dell001'

delete * from Product where Id='Dell002'

I try finding in google to solve it but I can't find solve

Comment: Please add some code examples of what you have, describe what you have tried, and the structure of your data, tables etc.

Comment: pls show the query u are running

Comment: See my blog post serries here: http://erikej.blogspot.dk/2015/04/sql-server-compact-adonet-data-access_29.html and http://erikej.blogspot.dk/2015/04/sql-server-compact-adonet-data-access.html

Comment: I update my code

Comment: @ErikEJ : I try using sqlceresultset but still very slow.

Comment: Do you have the required indexes?

Comment: @ErikEJ : no,I don't use any indexes

Comment: @ErikEJ : In http://erikej.blogspot.dk/2015/04/sql-server-compact-adonet-data-access_29.html : I see class public class CacheElement. This class support speedup executing query. Cause I don't write like this class